# Clear a list in Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

With this schema:

```
class XSet(db.Document):
    xs = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocument('X'))
#   ...

class X(db.Document):
    pass
```

Then:

```
 xset = XSet.objects(id="uniqueid").get()
 xs = xset.xs
```

How can I delete all the `X` instances stored in `xs`? (If possible, I'd very much like to stay within the Mongoengine abstraction.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about efficiency, but this works:

```
for x in xs:
  del x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$pullall` operator eg:

```
XSet.objects(pk=1).update(pull_all__xs=X)
```

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError: 'TopLevelDocumentMetaclass' object is not iterable` when trying this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, a slight variation on Ross' answer:

```
xset = XSet.objects(id="unique_id").get()
xset.update(pull_all__xs=xset.xs)
```